# GCP Terraform Lifecycle to ignore ssh-keys from instance metadata

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, metadata, ssh-keys

I've added the public ssh keys via the console to instance metadata on a GCE instance. But I want to ignore this change in terraform (don't want to add ssh keys in code) by using lifecycle ignore_changes. I've tried using the following but it doesn't work:

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      metadata.ssh-keys
    ]
  }
```

I know you can ignore ALL metadata but I don't want to do that. Just want to ignore ssh keys. What is the exact name I need to use as `metadata.ssh-keys` doesn't work? - terraform does not seem to recognise that and still has the ssh-keys in the plan.

Comment: "it doesn't work" - it is not specific. Why it does not work exactly? Any error messages? What is your TF code that generates the issue?

Comment: It doesn't work - terraform does not seem to recognise that and still has the ssh-keys in the plan. There are no error messages.

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is

```
 lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [metadata["ssh-keys"]]
  }
```